# Decrease Box-Shadow Margin Without Changing Content Margin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, margin, drop-shadow

I have a simple bootstrap website with the content surrounded by a drop-shadow.  I am trying to place the left and right drop-shadow closer towards the window borders to make the content look less crammed.  I am not wanting to increase the shadow radius, I just want the shadow sides to be placed closer to the left and right border.

Here's what it looks like: [Border is too close to content.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKGQI.png)

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="dropshadow">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

.dropshadow {
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

When I try to add padding or change the left and right margins of .dropshadow, I mess up the content's placement.  I want the content to stay where it is.  I would prefer to keep it as display: table, unless you think there is something better.

Here is fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/u1ph99pv/2/

Make sure you increase window width large enough for the box-shadow to appear, it's not a problem on my website because I don't display it on mobile view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to center-align your `div.dropshadow`?

`margin: 0 auto;` helps you do that. If you change from `auto` to a value, then your div will be automatically left-aligned. (padding doesn't affect the alignment of `div.dropshadow`)

One solution is: set padding (ex `padding: 0 50px`) for the parent of your `div.dropshadow` (right now it is < body >),

and set `display: block` for your`div.dropshadow`.

Please try it in you project. Looks like it works in the fiddle.

Comment: Thank you!  You fixed my problem and also read my mind!  I had to add 'margin: 0 auto' and change the display to table to reverse the auto left-alignment, because inline-block was suggested but didn't center anything!  So my mind was all set on keeping it at table, but I was misinformed.  Thank you, you're a genius angel demigod super hero level 99 wizard!!!